# Bigger and Smaller for numbers - Works in both directions?

Tags: terminology

I wanted to know how to use the right term when explaining the difference between numbers.

For example, I have two lenses:

Lens 1 = 10x zoom
Lens 2 = 5x zoom

I know I can say that the 1 has 2x bigger magnification, but can I say that lens 2 has 2x smaller magnification. Does it work both ways?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think 'twice as small' means the same thing as 'half as big'.  I'd say lens 2 has half the magnification of lens 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more an English language question.

Personally I do not think you can say Lens $1$ has "$2$ times bigger magnification" without ambiguity.

If you said it had $50\%$ more magnification, then this would be $1.5$ times Lens $2$'s magnification, so $100\%$ more magnification would be twice and logically $200\%$ more magnification would be three times.

Better to say Lens $1$ has $2$ times the magnification of Lens $2$, or Lens $1$ has twice the magnification of Lens $2$.  Then to reverse these you could say  Lens $2$ has $0.5$ times the magnification of Lens $1$, or Lens $2$ has half the magnification of Lens $1$.